# Listings Inside Macro

Tags: macros, listings

I am trying to figure out a way to have a macro where I demonstrate the output of a command then show the command via a `lstinline` command. I have read that I need to escape out the special char's (like `{` and `}`) and am now wondering if there is a way to do that automatically. Not sure if this is even possible.

Ideally, the `\commandExample{\qty{1.2}{\meter}}` command would produce `Output:1.2 m - Code:\qty{1.2}{\meter}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  caption           = {Missing Caption}
  ,label            = {lst:missingLabel}
  ,basicstyle       = \footnotesize\ttfamily %\footnotesize % \small\ttfamily
  ,frame            = shadowbox%
  ,numbers          = left%
  ,breaklines       = true%
  ,keywordstyle     = \color{darkgreen}%
  ,commentstyle     = \color{red}%
  ,tabsize          = 2%
  ,backgroundcolor  = \color{lightgrey}%
  %,texcsstyle       = {*\bf\color{blue}}%
  %,otherkeywords    = $, \{, \}, \[, \]%
  ,morekeywords     = {includegraphics }%
  ,moretexcs    =  {graphicspath}%
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\commandExample}{m}{%
  Output:#1 - Code:\lstinline{#1}} 

\begin{document}

\commandExample{begin}.

\unit{\meter}

%\commandExample{\unit{\meter}} % This line causes it to crash

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd absorb the argument verbatim and use `\tl_rescan:nn` to typeset it.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  caption           = {Missing Caption}
  ,label            = {lst:missingLabel}
  ,basicstyle       = \footnotesize\ttfamily
  ,frame            = shadowbox
  ,numbers          = left
  ,breaklines       = true
  ,keywordstyle     = \color{darkgreen}
  ,commentstyle     = \color{red}
  ,tabsize          = 2
  ,backgroundcolor  = \color{lightgrey}
  ,texcsstyle       = {*\bfseries\color{blue}}
  %,otherkeywords    = {$, \{, \}, \[, \]}
  ,morekeywords     = {includegraphics,unit}
  ,moretexcs    =  {graphicspath}%
  }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\commandExample}{v}
 {
  Output:~\tl_rescan:nn {} {#1} ~ - ~ Code:~\lstinline{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\commandExample{\unit{\meter}}

\commandExample{\textit{word}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Minor issue, most probably not relevant at all with the use-case the questioner has in mind: If you have `mathescape=true` in `\lstset`, then with `\commandExample` escaping to math via `$...$` seems broken. With `mathescape=true` the command `\lstinline{$x^2+y^2=2^2$}` seems to work, but `\commandExample{$x^2+y^2=2^2$}` gets me plenty of error messages of pattern `! Undefined control sequence.  \lst@arg ->$x`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez That's a “painting oneself in a corner” problem.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Anyway, using `mathescape` in this case would be nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

***Generally [the code provided by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640642/118714) is to be preferred to my code.***

*But the mathescape-mechanism, which is to be enabled via `\mathescape=true` within `\lstset`, and which allows to escape to math-mode within the argument of `\lstinline` via nesting things between `$...$`, is broken when applying `\lstinline` to the v-type  argument directly.*

*With mathescape enabled, the command `\lstinline{$x^2+y^2=2^2$}` gets you plenty of error messages of pattern `! Undefined control sequence.  \lst@arg ->$x` in case `$x^2+y^2=2^2$` was tokenized as a v-type-argument.*

*So if in the real-life-scenario you don't need the mathescape-feature, I recommend using egreg's code.*

*If in the real-life-scenario you do need the mathescape-feature, either modify egreg's answer so that `\commandExample` reads and tokenizes its argument under appropriate category code régime or try an approach where `\scantokens` or `\tl_rescan:nn` gets applied to the tokens passed to `\lstinline` as well.*

---

A minor issue is: With less recent LaTeX-distributions your code does not provide any definition for `\unit` and `\meter`. So in the example below the commands `\si` and `\metre` are used instead.

One problem is: A peculiarity of `\lstinline` is that the argument of `\lstinline` usually cannot be nested between `{` and `}` if it itself also contains `{`. In this case the argument needs to be nested between a character which does not occur within the argument. So `\lstinline{\unit{\meter}}` would not work out but you'd need to do something like `\lstinline|\unit{\meter}|`. (Another trick, which is done in egreg's answer, is having the argument of `\lstinline` tokenized under verbatim-catcode-régime so that in any case it does not contain `{` of category 1 or `}` of category 2. But `v`-type-category-code-régime breaks some features of `\lstinline`—at least the mathescape-feature.)

Another problem is that TeX expects the argument of `\lstinline` to be tokenized under different category code régime. Therefore `\lstinline` temporarily changes the category code régime for grabbing the tokens belonging to its argument from the token-stream. `\lstinline` relies on TeX needing to read from the .tex-input-file and to tokenize the tokens belonging to the argument under the changed category code régime so that they can be grabbed from the token-stream. Thus `\lstinline` only works on user-level/toplevel. `\lstinline` does not work when arguments are passed in after tokenizing them under unchanged category code régime as would be the case, e.g.,  when placing calls to `\lstinline` into the definition-texts of other macros which grab arguments under unchanged category code régime and pass them on to `\lstinline`.

This problem can be circumvented to some degree by having your macro `\commandExample` itself change the category code régime before grabbing the arguments and then passing them on to `\lstinline`, nested in `\scantokens{...%}`.

But hereby yet another problem arises: Neither LaTeX 2ε nor expl3 nor xparse provide a verbatim-argument-type which lets you preserve and pass on the verbatim-delimiter.

Therefore in the example below the command `\UDcollectverbarg` is provided which switches to verbatim catcode régime and grabs the argument both without and nested between the verbatim-delimiter so that these things can properly be passed on for further processing.

```latex
\makeatletter
%%======================Code for \UDcollectverbarg=============================
%% \UDcollectverbarg{<mandatory 1>}{<mandatory 2>}|<verbatim arg>|
%% 
%% reads <verbatim arg> under verbatim-catcode-regime and delivers:
%%
%%    <mandatory 1>{<mandatory 2>{<verbatim arg>}{|<verbatim arg>|}}
%%
%% Instead of verbatim-delimiter | the <verbatim arg> can be nested in braces.
%% You cannot use percent or spaces or horizontal tab as verbatim-delimiter.
%%
%% You can use <mandatory 1> for nesting calls to \UDcollectverbarg.
%% <mandatory 2> gets the <verbatim arg> twice: Once without verbatim-delimiters/braces,
%% once surrounded by verbatim-delimiters/braces.
%% Reason: When you feed it to \scantokens you don't need the verbatim-delimiters.
%%         When you use it for writing to temporary files and reading back,
%%         you need them.
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UDcollectverbarg[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother % <- this and the next line switch to
  \dospecials        %    verbatim-category-code-régime.
  \catcode`\{=1      % <- give opening curly brace the usual catcode so a 
                     %    curly-brace-balanced argument can be gathered in
                     %    case of the first thing of the verbatimized-argument 
                     %    being a curly opening brace.
  \catcode`\ =10     % <- give space and horizontal tab the usual catcode so \UD@collectverbarg
  \catcode`\^^I=10   %    cannot catch a space or a horizontal tab as its 4th undelimited argument.
                     %    (Its 4th undelimited argument denotes the verbatim-
                     %     syntax-delimiter in case of not gathering a
                     %     curly-brace-nested argument.)
  \catcode`\%=14     % <- make percent comment.
  \kernel@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {% seems a curly-brace-nested argument is to be caught:
    \catcode`\}=2    % <- give closing curly brace the usual catcode also.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{}%
  }{% seems an argument with verbatim-syntax-delimiter is to be caught:
    \do\{% <- give opening curly brace the verbatim-catcode again.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@collectverbarg[3]{%
  \do\ %   <- Now that \UD@collectverbarg has the delimiter or
  \do\^^I%    emptiness in its 4th arg, give space and horizontal tab
         %    the verbatim-catcode again.
  \do\^^M% <- Give the carriage-return-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \do\%%   <- Give the percent-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \long\def\@tempb##1#3{%
    \def\@tempb{##1}%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{%
      \def\@tempc{{##1}}%
    }{%
      \def\@tempc{#3##1#3}%
    }%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb % <- Turn characters into their "12/other"-pendants.
                               %    This may be important with things like the 
                               %    inputenc-package which may make characters 
                               %    active/which give them catcode 13(active).
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempc
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@@collectverbarg% <- this "spits out the result.
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\@tempb\expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\@tempc}{#1}{#2}%
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\UD@@collectverbarg[4]{%
  \endgroup
  #3{#4{#1}{#2}}%
}%
%%================= End of code for \UDcollectverbarg =========================
\makeatother
%%

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  % !!! Let's enable the mathescape-feature to test if it works:
  mathescape=true,
  % 
  caption           = {Missing Caption}
  ,label            = {lst:missingLabel}
  ,basicstyle       = \footnotesize\ttfamily %\footnotesize % \small\ttfamily
  ,frame            = shadowbox%
  ,numbers          = left%
  ,breaklines       = true%
  ,keywordstyle     = \color{darkgreen}%
  ,commentstyle     = \color{red}%
  ,tabsize          = 2%
  ,backgroundcolor  = \color{lightgrey}%
  %,texcsstyle       = {*\bf\color{blue}}%
  %,otherkeywords    = $, \{, \}, \[, \]%
  ,morekeywords     = {includegraphics }%
  ,moretexcs    =  {graphicspath}%
  }


\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\commandExample}{}{%
  \UDcollectverbarg{\@firstofone}{\@commandExample}%
}%
\begingroup
\catcode`\X=14 %
\catcode`\%=12 X
\csname @firstofone\endcsname{X
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand{\@commandExample}{mm}{X
    \scantokens{Output: #1 - Code: \lstinline#2%}X
  }X
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb:\commandExample{begin}: yields:

\commandExample{begin}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Both with \verb|\lstinline| and thus with this variant of \verb|\commandExample| you can't have
\verb|{|  within arguments that are nested between \verb|{...}|. Use some verbatim-delimiter instead:
\medskip

\verb:\commandExample|\si{\metre}|: yields:

\commandExample|\si{\metre}|

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent  \verb|mathescape|-thingies in the code seem to work, too:
\medskip

\verb:\commandExample|$x^2+y^2=z^2$|: yields:

\commandExample|$x^2+y^2=z^2$|

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\verb:\commandExample{$x^2+y^2=z^2$}: yields:

\commandExample{$x^2+y^2=z^2$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I realize that. I am trying to update a cls file from 2015 to more modern times as it uses a few packages that a "We therefore do not recommend its usage at this point in time" listing.